# Como obter todas as constantes de uma classe?

Tags: c#, reflexão

Meu projeto tem uma classe *helper* com várias constantes que representam *roles* pré-definidas.

```
public static class RolesHelper
{
    public const string ModuloUsuarios = "Usuarios";
    public const string ModuloMenus = "Menus";
    public const string ModuloBanners = "Banners";
    public const string ModuloGaleriaFotos = "GaleriasFotos";
    public const string ModuloProgramacao = "Programacao";
    public const string ModuloMetaTags = "MetaTags";
    public const string ModuloNoticias = "Noticias";
    public const string ModuloPaginas = "Paginas";
}
```

No método `Seed` (método usado pelo Entity Framework para atualizar a base de dados), eu preciso fazer com que determinado usuário seja relacionado com estes valores.

Atualmente, existe um método `AdicionarUsuarioARole()` que faz o trabalho todo, e este método é chamado várias vezes, desta forma:

```
AdicionarUsuarioARole(user, RolesHelper.ModuloUsuarios);
AdicionarUsuarioARole(user, RolesHelper.ModuloMenus);
//E assim por diante
```

---

O que eu quero é obter **todas as constantes** públicas desta classe numa coleção, para fazer iterá-la e chamar o método **`AdicionarUsuarioARole()`** com cada valor desta coleção. Desta forma, não preciso me preocupar em atualizar o método `Seed` sempre que eu adicionar uma constante nesta classe.

Por exemplo:

```
var listaConstantes = RolesHelper.GetAllConstantValues();

foreach(var constVal in listaConstantes)
{
    AdicionarUsuarioARole(user, constVal);
}
```

Comment: Será que pode te ajudar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261824/how-can-i-get-all-constants-of-a-type-by-reflection @jbueno?

Comment: Não sei, escreve uma resposta aí :p

Comment: Deu nem tempo, rs! O Cigano já colocou uma resposta igual tá no link que postei acima!

Comment: Você não pode escrever um método estático na sua classe Helper que retorna essa list/array de constantes?

Comment: Posso @igorventurelli Mas por que eu faria isso se posso capturar todas as constantes usando reflection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// Lista todos os campos públicos e estáticos, 
// tanto da classe quanto das classes-base

foreach (var prop in typeof(SuaClasse)
                     .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | 
                                BindingFlags.Static | 
                                BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
{
    // IsLiteral determina que o valor foi criado em tempo de compilação,
    //    e não pode ser alterado.
    // IsInitOnly determina que o valor pode ser alterado no corpo do
    //    construtor.
    if(prop.IsLiteral && !prop.IsInitOnly) 
    {
        // Valor do campo
        var valor = prop.GetValue(null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

Usando Linq fica bem simples:

```
var constantes = typeOf(RolesHelper).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
                                               BindingFlags.Static |
                                               BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
                     .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly)
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Raios! Nem posso ver seus movimentos!

Comment: Quase a mesma coisa da sua, na verdade :)